# Qual a diferença entre as funções wraps e update_wrapper do módulo funtools

Tags: python, python-3.x

No módulo `functools` da `bibliotaca padrão` do `Python` existem duas funções `update_wrapper` e `wraps` na documentação da função `wraps` temos:

> This is a convenience function for invoking `update_wrapper()` as a
>   function decorator when defining a wrapper function. It is equivalent
>   to `partial(update_wrapper, wrapped=wrapped, assigned=assigned,
>   updated=updated)`.

Eu sei que a função `update_wrapper` é chamada internamente por `wraps`, gostaria de um exemplo onde se faça necessário o uso da função `update_wrapper` e não de `wraps`.

Comment: [Pergunta relacionada](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15357776/what-is-the-difference-between-functools-wraps-and-update-wrapper) no Soen

Comment: A resposta do @nosklo explica bem. `update_wrapper()` faz a magia toda e `wraps()` serve para usar  `update_wrapper` como decorator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Na verdade das duas funções, a única que faz alguma coisa é a `update_wrapper`. Ela copia, entre outras coisas, `__module__`, `__name__`, `__qualname__`, `__annotations__` e `__doc__` de uma função para outra.

Já a função `wraps` não faz nada em si, simplesmente chama a `update_wrapper`. O que muda são os parâmetros... Para a primeira função, você tem que passar as duas funções como parâmetro ao mesmo tempo, a de origem e a de destino da cópia:

```
resultado = update_wrapper(x, y) # copia de y para x
```

Já para a segunda você tem que passar os parâmetros separadamente:

```
tmp = wraps(y)
tmp(x)      #copia de y pra x
```

ou

```
wraps(y)(x)  #copia de y pra x
```

A razão é facilitar a utilização como decorador, afinal, o que a sintaxe de decorador `@` faz é chamar a função passando a outra como parâmetro:

```
@wraps(y)
def x(...):
    ....
```

Isso permite definir a função e *"wrappar"* ela diretamente, em uma sequencia só de comandos.

RESUMINDO, `wraps` é uma função de conveniência que chama `update_wrapper` para você de uma forma que fica mais fácil usá-la como decorador.

Comment: Mais uma vez obrigado pela resposta.